# Testing different resolutions for RWD

Tags: protractor

I would like to know what is best way to do test for different device resolution.
I have 3 different resolutions and all tests has to pass .
Problem at moment I see is duplicated of code in every resolution. How do it nicely that can be easy reusable.

Can you give me example how it should be done .

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using environment variables, i.e. in your onPrepare block / file:

```
if (process.env.E2E_CUSTOM_WIDTH && process.env.E2E_CUSTOM_HEIGHT) {
  // e.g. from the command line (before running the tests)
  //  $ export E2E_CUSTOM_WIDTH=1400
  //  $ export E2E_CUSTOM_HEIGHT=900
  browser.manage().window().setPosition(0, 0); // top left
  // I've put this in global for simplicity, you may want to change that
  global.fixedWidth  = parseInt(process.env.E2E_CUSTOM_WIDTH);
  global.fixedHeight = parseInt(process.env.E2E_CUSTOM_HEIGHT);
  browser.manage().window().setSize(global.fixedWidth, global.fixedHeight);
}
```

So no code duplication for your tests, just run protractor with the proper configuration matrix by manipulating environment variables in your shell.

Other option is using separate protractor configuration files with the browser window sizes variations.